# Execute controller method on startup (Grails)

Tags: grails, controllers

I have an event controller with a populate() method which adds events from a JSON link to my database. I want this to occur on startup of my server.

I've tried various things in my Bootstrap file. Such as:

```
def event = new EventController.populate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should move that code into a service and out of your controller. This gives you a lot more options, including injecting the service into your `Bootstrap.groovy` and calling the method on startup of the application.

That's a much more proper Grails solution.

Comment: What other options might putting it in a service give me? I'm a novice to Grails

Comment: A service can also implement the `org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean` interface which allows you to put code into the `afterPropertiesSet` method. This will be run once the bean is created in the context of the application. Which is useful when you don't want to rely on `Bootstrap.groovy`. Just as another example. Services have their own usefulness beyond your use case too. They are singleton, typically stateless, can be injected into other services, controllers, tag libraries, even domain classes. Plus they are easy to test too.